# Time picker format changes ,When inserting into database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, timepicker

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" name="shiftStartTime" id="shiftStartTime" required parsley-maxlength="6" placeholder="Shift Start Time" />
</div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.timepicker').wickedpicker();

    });   

</script>
```

Controller code :

```
$shiftstarttime = $this->input->post('shiftStartTime');
```

But it is inserting into database as "00:00:12".How to change it to the H:m:s format (ie 12:05:10)

Comment: what is the column type in the database?

Comment: Its time type....

Comment: please use strtotime php function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to confirm that in post you are getting correct value if yes then following would work for you

```
$input = $this->input->post('shiftStartTime');
$input = str_replace(" : ", ":", $input);
$shiftstarttime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($input));
```

Comment: By using this method,Time stored in database as 05:30:00 even if any time inserted.

Comment: What value you get before inserting into database. What is the post value? Would you please print it first and check what is the value there?

Comment: Inputting value is correct. I just printed it. But the value entered into database is wrong

Comment: Could you please let me know which format is there in Inputting value you get printed?

Comment: For Eg:5 : 37 PM

Comment: Okay would you please try again with my updated answer? First replace input.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
it give's you currect value

```
<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" name="shiftStartTime" id="shiftStartTime" required placeholder="HH:MM:SS" />
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
         'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
    });
</script>
```

Controller code

```
$shiftstarttime = $this->input->post('shiftStartTime');
```

make sure column type in the database is time

Answer (score 0):

First, check when you getting time form date picker, it's coming in which form.

Otherwise, you can specifically change format on the controller side then assign that value to the database object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it will work for you.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({});
});
</script>
```